# Testing: What to do With Setup Logic That Doesn't Apply to One Test?

Tags: testing, selenium

I've noticed a problem that seems to crop up with several of my otherwise cleanly organized  Selenium test classes (though the problem could equally apply to unit or other feature/acceptance tests).  I'll have a bunch of tests that are all logically grouped together:

1. login with valid password
2. login with valid password and go to page Foo
3. login with valid password and go to page Bar
4. login with valid password and then log out

etc.

All of these tests have "login" as part of them, so I add that to the setUp method:

```
self.login("fake@example.com", "testuser", "testpassword")
```

But then I need to add one more test to the suite:

1. fail to login with invalid password

And then I'm not sure what to do, because that test doesn't do the same login action as the others.

At this point, I'm left with several different options ... none of which I really like:

- Start a whole other suite just for that last test (even though it logically belongs with the others)
- Leave the setUp logic, but make my last test logout as its first action (which results in the test doing a pointless login/logout before even starting)
- Leave the setUp logic, but add a line to the setup to skip the login if we're on the last test (ie. `if self._testMethodName == "last test" ...`, but this just feels hacky)
- Take the login out of the setUp (but then I have login lines in every other test in the suite, which don't really add anything to the test)

My question is: which of the above approaches is the "best practice" (or is there a fifth option that I'm missing which is the real best practice)?

Comment: you should override your SetUp with a different login that has invalid credential

Comment: So you'd argue for having another suite/class?

Answer (score 1):

If you're testing the login page of the application, then why you're placing the tests inside the setup() method.

I believe setup method is used to set the environment for your tests. eg. Opening the browser, Loading the website/ application etc.,

You could use different Test method for testing the login page, and you can pass various inputs to test it.

Comment: I guess I chose bad examples; I was trying to illustrate a general problem, but it sounds like you got bogged down by my specific cases.  Forget login tests.  Let's say I have 5 tests that do foo-related things, but one of them needs to login as a different user.  Now do I put that last test in a different suite, or do I use (hacky) logic in my setUp to login as a different user for that one test only,  or do I take the logging in out of the setUp, or ...?

Comment: In that case, logging in can be grouped out of the setup, since even if you need to have few more users to log in to do a same set of tests , it will be easier to handle. Going for different suite may not be a good idea.